# How to prove the PRF, $F(k,x) = (k \wedge x ) \oplus k$ is PRP?

Tags: pseudo-random-function, pseudo-random-permutation

I am trying to understand PRF's and PRP's. I have got a question where I have to decide whether $F(k,x) = (k \wedge x ) \oplus k$ (where $k$ and $x$ are simple $1$ bits (1 or 0)) is PRP or not. I am not sure if I understand PRP's correctly. As I have found:

> A Pseudo Random Permutation is a PRF that happens to have the property that every element in the input domain has a single associated member in the output co-domain and vice versa.

So what I have got in my example.

```
k x F(k,x)
0 0 0
0 1 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
```

For each couple, I have an associated member in output co-domain, but for each output 0 and 1. I do not have a unique member in the input domain. So this function is not PRP. Am I right?

Comment: As there exists no such F'(k, y) that gives a chance to restore value of x for k = 0 that is the problem?

Comment: yes, that is the problem.

Comment: For some reason you seem to be working under the premise that the function is a PRF. That premise is wrong.

Comment: @Maeher yes, I do. Why is it wrong?

Comment: Because it's trivially distinguishable from a random function.

Comment: Yes, It's not a secure PRF, but it still could be an insecure PRF.

Comment: It's not a PRF. Indistinguishability is part of the definition of PRF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition tries to say that a permutation must be invertible.

When the key is $0$, we can not determine the inverse of 0 and the inverse of 1 doesn't exist.